# How to generate SharedKeyLite for Azure Table Storage REST request

Tags: javascript, azure, postman, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to call Azure Table Storage using Postman but keep getting :

> Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of
>   Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

The code I am using for the pre-call script in Postman is as follows:

```
var storageAccount = "**mystorageaccount**";
var accountKey = "**mystoragekey**";

var date = new Date();
var UTCstring = date.toUTCString();

var data = date + "\n" + "/**mystorageaccount**/**mytable**"

var encodedData = unescape(encodeURIComponent(data));

var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(encodedData, accountKey);
var signature = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

var auth = "SharedKeyLite " + storageAccount + ":" + signature;

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("auth", auth);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("date", UTCstring);
```

The headers in Postman are as follows:

```
Authorization : {{auth}}
date : {{date}}
version : 2015-12-11
```

I am guessing the issue may be with the data variable, but running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because you're not converting your account key to a buffer. Please change the following line of code:

```
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(encodedData, accountKey);
```

to

```
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(encodedData, Buffer.from(accountKey, 'base64'));
```

And you should not get the error.

---

**UPDATE**

I also got the same error. Please try the following code:

```
var storageAccount = "**mystorageaccount**";
var accountKey = "**mystoragekey**";

var date = new Date();
var UTCstring = date.toUTCString();

var data = UTCstring + "\n" + "/**mystorageaccount**/**mytable**"

var encodedData = unescape(encodeURIComponent(data));

var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(encodedData, CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(accountKey));
var signature = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

var auth = "SharedKeyLite " + storageAccount + ":" + signature;

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("auth", auth);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("date", UTCstring);
```

I just tried the code above and was able to list entities in my table.

Comment: I made the change and now I am getting TypeError: t.clamp is not a function

Comment: Brilliant, thanks, also spotted the mistake in line 4 (date should be UTCString)... have accepted this answer as it's all working now, thanks

Comment: Just done further testing, while this works great for GET and POST, DELETE fails. I have tried adding the (PartitionKey='x',RowKey='x') to the end of the data variable but no joy (getting 403). Would you be able to post the modification I need to make for a DELETE request? Thanks