# Azure Table Storage (Table Services REST API) SharedKeyLite not working

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

After seeing through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56512864/how-to-generate-sharedkeylite-for-azure-table-storage-rest-request), I tried the same in my postman.

```
var storageAccount = "mystorage";
var accountKey = "<<primaryKey>>";

var date = new Date();
var UTCstring = date.toUTCString();

var data = UTCstring + "\n" +  "/mystorage/Health"

var encodedData = unescape(encodeURIComponent(data));

var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(encodedData, CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(accountKey));
var signature = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
var auth = "SharedKeyLite " + storageAccount + ":" + signature;

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("auth", auth);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("date", UTCstring);
```

When I make the request to ATS, to the following url,
[image]

I get the auth denied!
[image]

Can someone please guide me what's going wrong here?!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to generate a bearer token and put it to the Authorization of Postman.

If you are using C#, you can use this to get the bearer token:

```
AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
string accesstoken = azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://storage.azure.com/").Result;
string bearertoken = "Bearer " + accesstoken;
```

Then Copy the bearer token:

[image]

After that, it should be ok.

Comment: I tried this and it din work... As per this link, the word Bearer isn't required
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/policies/generate-shared-access-signature

Comment: @Raghav I am not sure, what is 'din work'? didn't or did?

Comment: Am Sorry @Bowman. It did not work. The keyword Bearer shouldn't be there in the Authrorization header for Shared Signature Access. For JWT tokens it is mandatory. The above example you shared is a AAD JWT token

Answer (score 2):

Just realized that the url and the `data` that we are encoding should exactly match the url we are querying...
After changing

```
var data = UTCstring + "\n" +  "/mystorage/Health"
```

to

```
var data = UTCstring + "\n" +  "/mystorage/Health(PartitionKey='USA',RowKey='WA')"
```

things started working.

Update :
It just expects the right table query. The following works fine,

```
var data = UTCstring + "\n" +  "/mystorage/Health()"
```

with all filter expressions in the url being invoked from postman.